# I need has_perm() example for AbstractBaseUser in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, authentication, permissions

I have a Custom User Model, and I need to give permissions to users with certain roles (fields in user model) but I couldn't find any examples on the internet, so I'm asking for examples from anybody who has done this before. Here's my Abstract user model for reference:

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    
    class RoleChoices(models.TextChoices):
        admin = 'Admin', _('Admin')
        cashier = 'Cashier', _('Cashier')
        waiter = 'Waiter', _('Waiter')
        courier = 'Courier', _('Courier')
        customer = 'Customer', _('Customer')
    
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), unique=True, max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=100)
    surname = models.CharField(_('surname'), max_length=100)
    phone_number = models.CharField(_('phone_number'), max_length=100, null=True, default='Invalid Phone Number')
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=RoleChoices.choices, default=RoleChoices.customer)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'surname']

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_joined', ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

Thanks in advance, and Please excuse any grammatical errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create custom permissions for a given model object, use the `permissions` attribute of the `Meta` class.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
    class Meta:
        permissions = [
            ("change_role", "Can change the role of user"),
            # Others customs permissions if needed
        ]
```

If you now want to check if an user has the permission to **change role** then :
**In the .py** file `user.has_perm('app.change_role')` *app* is the name of the app in which the model is defined.

**In the template file (.html)**
The currently logged user permissions has stored in the `{{ perms }}` template variable. Use it as follow :

```
{% if perms.app_label.change_role %}
    <!-- Show whatever you need here -->
{% endif %}
```

**NB :** This requires the following context processor to be enabled : `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`

And note also that **if you're logged in as a superuser**, `perms.app_label.foobar` will always be true, even if you misspelled the permission name.

**Also , if you want to see all permissions a user has due to the groups he belongs to, launch Django shell...**

```
user = User.objects.get(username='somename')
user.get_group_permissions()
```

**If you want add view level permissions**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Only user with app_name.change_role can access this url
@permission_required('app_name.change_role')
# Also protect the view with authenticated user
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def my_protected_view(request):
    # Do your secrets things here
```

Comment: Firstly, Thanks For Your Detailed Answer, That Helped A Lot To Understand What's Going On. I Have A Problem With **Defining** The Permissions That User Have with has_perm() or has_perms() And I Wanna Use Role Field To Assign Any Permission.

Comment: I would like to help you, but i don't understand your question ! What is the goal ? Be simple

Comment: I want to restrict waiter and cashier users from going to some pages that can change the DB data. I only want to authorize admin for that.

Comment: How, i see. For that, you can define some `urls` link in template like this: `{% if user.is_staff %} <a href="{% url 'only_admin_url' %}"></a> {% endif %}`. Note that you can use **is_staff** to check if the user has admin right or **is_superuser** who has all the permissions. [Django user model documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff)

Comment: I Know That But, There Would Be Vulnerabilities If I Do That. Like Client That Writes Some Restricted Url To The Browser And Access It.

Comment: I updated the answer with [views level permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication#views).

Comment: That Would Do What I Want. Thanks For Your Time.